# Alternative way to get data from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, wcf, ado.net

Im working on a WCF + MVC application and I'm not using Entity Framework. What I would like to do is to get data out of my "Customer" table (Which currently has like 13 "customers") and post it to a Chart in MVC. I stumbled upon this code from Microsofts site :

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");
    var data = db.Query("SELECT Name, Price FROM Product");
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Product Sales")
        .DataBindTable(dataSource: data, xField: "Name")
        .Write();
}
```

But I'm not using Entity Framework, and my Database is in a class library that communicates with my WCF, which is then being referenced through a ServiceReference in my MVC project.

So my question is, what would correspond to `var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");` and

```
.DataBindTable(dataSource: data, xField: "Name")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataSource` can be just an `IEnumerable`; as long as you specify an existing property on the `xField` you should be able to view your graph.

Comment: Ah ok, I see, what about the connection itself? How would i "Open" it?

Comment: @Kingkong depends, a SQLServer connection? MySQL connection? A CSV? Search on StackOverflow for your specific connection driver.